# Microsoft Outlook Calendar Peek - Disable hiding past events

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

I would really like to be able to see all events for the current day in the calendar peek, even those that are in the past.

By default, if I have an event from 7-8am, as soon as 8:00am hits, that event disappears from my Calendar Peek. The screenshot I am including should show what I mean easily. I don't see any settings for this, so I don't really know if it's possible.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: According to the reply from Steve in this TechNet thread, the To-Do Bar displays 7 days upcoming appointments. There is no option to change this. I’d like to recommend you post a feedback in Outlook UserVoice forum

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/002d3bf8-3c47-411c-9594-8cf86b023553/outlook-2016-todo-bar-number-of-upcoming-appointments-shown-not-configurable?forum=outlook

Comment: @Perry Thank you. So unfortunately this is probably not configurable, but my best option is to at least share feedback to Microsoft. Will do.

Comment: Thanks, these comments hinted that in order to look at past events I need to use Calendar View instead of the To-Do bar. That's good enough for me.